# Callback with prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a problem with class.property.

```
    function myTuwas(){
        this.was = "tuwas";
    }
    myTuwas.prototype.setData = function(){
        console.log("tuwas", typeof this.was)
    }

    function myClass(){
        this.myVar = "hello";
    }
    myClass.prototype.setData = function(callback){
        console.log(typeof callback);
        callback();
    }

    var myInst = new myClass();
    var myInstTuwas = new myTuwas();
    myInst.setData(myInstTuwas.setData);
```

If i call myInstTuwas.setData than this.was is defined, but if use myInstTuwas.setData as a parameter and use it as a callback function
in myInst.setData than this.was is undefined. what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the context to callback function.

```
myClass.prototype.setData = function(callback,ctx){
    console.log(typeof callback);
    callback.call(ctx);
}
```

//when you set data

```
myInst.setData(myInstTuwas.setData, myInstTuwas);
```

Comment: Vengat7668, thanks a lot of for your fast and good response.. it is working with both solutions...

Answer (score 0):

The context depends on how your code calls to a function:

```
function myTuwas(){
    this.was = "tuwas";
}
myTuwas.prototype.setData = function(){
    console.log("tuwas", typeof this.was)
}
```

Here you have defined a "class" called myTuwas, and it has a method "setData", so the following code works as expected:

```
var temp= new myTuwas();
temp.setData();
```

but it works because when you call a function using the format "variable.function()" Javascript automatically sets "this" as the variable.
On the other hand, this code, it won't work as you expects:

```
var temp= new myTuwas();
var setData= temp.setData;
setData();
```

Because in this call there is no reference to the object in the calling sentence, so "this" is not defined. In strict mode this will be `undefined`. If you aren't in strict mode, this will be the global context (`this === window` in a browser). Actually, this has the same outcome that this code, obtaining the function directly from the prototype:

```
var setData=myTuwas.prototype.setData;
setData();
```

How to solve that? pass the object AND the callback function to the myClass.setData function and use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function setData(context,callbackFn) {
    callbackFn.apply(context);
}
```

Comment: Pablo, thanks a lot of for your fast and good response.. it is working with both solutions...

Comment: Please select a response as "the accepted answer". If not, the question will remain "unanswered" for the stats ;)